# Most Significant Byte Computation

Tags: c++, endianness

I am trying to implement a four byte value (most significant data first) to compute the total length of data. I found a code snippet to compute this but I didn't get a 4 byte data in the output. Instead I only got a 2 byte value.

```
char bytesLen[4] ;
unsigned int blockSize = 535;
bytesLen[0] = (blockSize & 0xFF);
bytesLen[1] = (blockSize >> 8) & 0xFF;
bytesLen[2] = (blockSize >> 16) & 0xFF;
bytesLen[3] = (blockSize >> 24) & 0xFF;

std::cout << "bytesLen: " << bytesLen << '\n';
```

Did I missed something in my code?

Comment: This rather looks like code which converts from big to little endian.

Answer (score 3):

No, you didn't. You're outputting the array as a C string, which is `null` terminated. The third byte is nul so only two characters will be shown.

This is not a rational way to output binary values.

Also you're saving least significant byte first, not most significant. For most significant you have to reverse the order of the bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Do you have example on how to fix it?

Comment: You don't. You're done.  Just stop using your char arr like it's null terminated.

Answer (score 3):

This shows how to do the same thing without shift operators and bitmasks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
// C++11
#include <cstdint>

int main(void)
{
    // with union, the memory allocation is shared
    union {
        uint8_t bytes[4];
        uint32_t n;
    } length;

    // see htonl if needs to be in network byte order
    //  or ntohl if from network byte order to host
    length.n = 535;

    std::cout << std::hex;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        std::cout << (unsigned int)length.bytes[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fixed code [untested].  Note this won't compile as is.  You'll need to reorder it slightly, but it should help:

```
unsigned char bytesLen[4] ;
unsigned int blockSize = 535;

// little endian
#if 0
bytesLen[0] = (blockSize & 0xFF);
bytesLen[1] = (blockSize >> 8) & 0xFF;
bytesLen[2] = (blockSize >> 16) & 0xFF;
bytesLen[3] = (blockSize >> 24) & 0xFF;

// big endian
#else
bytesLen[3] = (blockSize & 0xFF);
bytesLen[2] = (blockSize >> 8) & 0xFF;
bytesLen[1] = (blockSize >> 16) & 0xFF;
bytesLen[0] = (blockSize >> 24) & 0xFF;
#endif

char tmp[9];

char *
pretty_print(char *dst,unsigned char *src)
{
    char *hex = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    char *bp = dst;
    int chr;

    for (int idx = 0;  idx <= 3;  ++idx) {
        chr = src[idx];
        *bp++ = hex[(chr >> 4) & 0x0F];
        *bp++ = hex[(chr >> 0) & 0x0F];
    }

    *bp = 0;

    return dst;
}

std::cout << "bytesLen: " << pretty_print(tmp,bytesLen) << '\n';
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Based upon your followup question, to concatenate binary data, we can *not* use string-like functions such as `sprintf` [because the binary data may have 0x00 inside, which would stop the string transfer short].  Also, if the binary data had *no* 0x00 in it, the string functions would run beyond the end of the array(s) looking for it, and *bad things* would happen. The string functions also assume *signed* `char` data and when dealing with raw binary, we want to use `unsigned char`.

Here's something to try:

```
unsigned char finalData[1000];  // size is just example
unsigned char bytesLen[4];
unsigned char blockContent[300];

unsigned char *dst;

dst = finalData;

memcpy(dst,bytesLen,sizeof(bytesLen));
dst += sizeof(bytesLen);

memcpy(dst,blockContent,sizeof(blockContent));
dst += sizeof(blockContent);

// append more if needed in similar way ...
```

Note: The above presupposes that `blockContent` is of fixed size.  If it were to have a variable number of bytes, we'd need to replace `sizeof(blockContent)` with (e.g.) `bclen` where that is the number of bytes in `blockContent`

Comment: Why not just cast each byte to int and print it with `std::hex` set? No need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @Lundin Yes.  But, since OP is [quite] new to C/C++ it doesn't hurt to show how `std::hex` would do it [similarly].  IMO, before one uses a given `std::*`, etc., one should write one [or at least be capable of doing so] for basic stuff like this.  Doing it manually here is particularly important to the understanding of what's really going on overall here. It also illustrates "nibble slicing", which is useful. (e.g. a month from now, OP will/would find `std::hex` on their own, have an "aha" moment and realize how to recode this using it).

Comment: Well... even further down their programming career, they may look at this code and think "Hmm why store binary data in implementation-defined-signedness characters? Wouldn't that potentially cause any given byte to become a negative value, and when he converts it to `int` it preserves the signedness. And then when he right-shifts that potentially negative int he invokes implementation-defined behavior... the int could contain any data at this point." ->

Comment: "Then silently, with no comments, he dodges the bug by masking away a least significant portion of the data. Did he dodge that subtle but severe bug by luck or intentionally? It appears that he might as well have written a subtle bug there, just because he wanted to re-invent the wheel."

Comment: @Lundin I've changed the buffer to unsigned [was OP's choice, but, yes, more correct as adjusted]. I knew about the sign issue [in print], which is why I added the mask in the first place--which is needed even if unsigned [_no_ issue leaving it signed, however, as print will always work]. And, I "reinvented the wheel" as a teaching tool here. Signedness and "print vs std::hex" are two separate issues. Using `std::hex` would have glossed over one of the conceptual problems OP was having. I wrote my first hex dump program back in 1973 [and many more since], so I'm quite aware of the issues.

Comment: The main issue is that the native, primitive data types such as `char` and `int` are used together with bitwise operators. That's always questionable practice, not only because of signedness concerns, but also because of potential implicit type promotions.

Comment: @Lundin None of that breaks the code here. Shifting an `int` and then masking against it is perfectly fine. Type promotions? We're setting an `int` from an `unsigned char` [now]. I've been writing kernel/driver code [in C since 1981--earlier on other systems] and I've never found a bug [out of many that I have] that is based upon anything re. type promotions in this context. If it were truly an issue, Linux wouldn't boot because the code does _plenty_ of shifting/masking/or'ing/and'ing against signed integral types.  Also, note that `open(2)`'s `flags` parameter is `int` and it's a bit mask

Comment: @CraigEstey I'm now trying to prefix the output to my actual block of data so that the block have a prefix consisting a four byte binary value of block size (represented by bytesLen). Will this code work sprintf(finalData, "%s%s", bytesLen, blockContent);

Comment: No, but, I've updated my answer with a method that will work [also the reason why what you want to try wouldn't]

Comment: Note that your `sprintf` would be fine if `byteLens` and `blockContent` were `char *` style strings (e.g. "abc" and "def" respectively).  So, keep the example handy. You may not be able to use it here, but it's a perfectly valid way to do string concatenation in general.

Comment: It's quite easy to come up some scenario where promotions would cause havoc because of sloppy use of types:  `unsigned char u8; ... int plain_int = u8 - 256; plain_int <<= n;` And there upon left shift you have undefined behavior. Caused by the `u8` implicitly changing type, which could have been avoided without the sloppy use of plain integer types/literals.

Comment: Also Linux is a horrible example to hold up as some sort of canon, since it is full of non-standard C extensions and reliance on implementation-defined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you want ms byte first, then you've reversed the order of the bytes.

You get incorrect output because you treat everything as a C string even though it is not. Get rid of the `char` type and fix the printing.

In C++, it would be like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
  uint8_t bytesLen[sizeof(uint32_t)];
  uint32_t blockSize = 535;

  bytesLen[3] = (blockSize >>  0) & 0xFF;
  bytesLen[2] = (blockSize >>  8) & 0xFF;
  bytesLen[1] = (blockSize >> 16) & 0xFF;
  bytesLen[0] = (blockSize >> 24) & 0xFF;

  bool removeZeroes = true;
  std::cout << "bytesLen: 0x";
  for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof(bytesLen); i++)
  {
    if(bytesLen[i] != 0)
    {
      removeZeroes = false;
    }

    if(!removeZeroes)
    {
      std::cout << std::hex << (int)bytesLen[i];
    }
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. Now I'm trying to prepend the byteLen output to my char* array.

Comment: @bluueee Why would you need a char array? It doesn't make any sense. If you want to represent the output as a string, use std::string. You could replace cout with stringstream in the above code, for example.

Comment: Is this the correct way to prepend it:  sprintf(data, "%s%s", bytesLen, content);  What I'm trying to do here is to add the four byte binary value of the length before the actual data content. As this is the required data format of the receiving application.